# Infiniband vs. Gigabit ethernet, how do I control which is used by an MPI program

Tags: mpi, ethernet, infiniband, mvapich2

I have an MPI program that runs on a computer cluster that has both ethernet and Infiniband connectivity.  When I compile with mpavich2's mpicc, it automatically links to the Infiniband libraries.

Is there a way to control which network is used when compiling an mpi program?

I checked the man page for mpicc and it was not useful for this.

Comment: This is independent of `mpicc`, but on the launcher you are using to run the application. This question is probably best directed at the administrators of the system, because they know the actual installation.

Comment: With MVAPICH2, devices are configured both when the library is compiled and when the program is executed. Refer to [the manual](http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/userguide/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading about this, it seams that it depends on the MPI library used.  For instance, with mvapich2 the type of interconnect is an configurable option when building the library (see the [docs](http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/static/media/mvapich/mvapich2-2.1-userguide.pdf)).  For OpenMPI it appears to be a runtime option when executing mpirun (see man page of mpirun or the [web docs](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=openfabrics#ib-btl)).